# yum install gcc error

Tags: yum

```
# yum install gcc
Loaded plugins: rhnplugin, security
Excluding Packages in global exclude list
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gcc.x86_64 0:4.1.2-50.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: cpp = 4.1.2-50.el5 for package: gcc
--> Processing Dependency: libgomp >= 4.1.2-50.el5 for package: gcc
--> Processing Dependency: libgcc >= 4.1.2-50.el5 for package: gcc
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-devel >= 2.2.90-12 for package: gcc
--> Running transaction check
---> Package cpp.x86_64 0:4.1.2-50.el5 set to be updated
---> Package glibc-devel.x86_64 0:2.5-58 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers = 2.5-58 for package: glibc-devel
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.5-58 for package: glibc-devel
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-headers for package: glibc-devel
---> Package libgcc.i386 0:4.1.2-50.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libgcc.x86_64 0:4.1.2-50.el5 set to be updated
---> Package libgomp.x86_64 0:4.4.4-13.el5 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
--> Processing Dependency: glibc = 2.5-49.el5_5.7 for package: nscd
---> Package glibc.i686 0:2.5-58 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: glibc-common = 2.5-58 for package: glibc
---> Package glibc.x86_64 0:2.5-58 set to be updated
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.5-58 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-headers >= 2.2.1 for package: glibc-headers
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-headers for package: glibc-headers
--> Running transaction check
---> Package glibc-common.x86_64 0:2.5-58 set to be updated
---> Package glibc-headers.x86_64 0:2.5-58 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-headers >= 2.2.1 for package: glibc-headers
--> Processing Dependency: kernel-headers for package: glibc-headers
---> Package nscd.x86_64 0:2.5-58 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
glibc-headers-2.5-58.x86_64 from rhel-x86_64-server-5 has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: kernel-headers is needed by package glibc-headers-2.5-58.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-5)
glibc-headers-2.5-58.x86_64 from rhel-x86_64-server-5 has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: kernel-headers >= 2.2.1 is needed by package glibc-headers-2.5-58.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-5)
Error: Missing Dependency: kernel-headers is needed by package glibc-headers-2.5-58.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-5)
Error: Missing Dependency: kernel-headers >= 2.2.1 is needed by package glibc-headers-2.5-58.x86_64 (rhel-x86_64-server-5)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
The program package-cleanup is found in the yum-utils package.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you just need to:

```
yum install kernel-headers
```

Comment: yes that and it turns out my rem repository has excluded kernel* from being updated.